# Can XmlJavaTypeAdapter marshal object to another object?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Can XmlJavaTypeAdapter marshal from ClassA object to ClassB object? So that when :

```
public void createClassB (ClassB b) { }
```

I can pass in ClassA object. Does it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can, but not quite like this. I mean you can not pass a `ClassA` object, where `ClassB` is required, unless `ClassA` is a sub-class of `ClassB`. Read through [this example](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2005/09/30/using-jaxb-20s-xmljavatypeadapter), its showing how you can marshal a `Currency` object as a `String` into your XML. So, quiet similar to the example, you should be able to marshal ClassA object to ClassB or something.

Comment: Hi thanks the example very clear, so which mean there is no way to use xmljavatypeadapter so that i pass in ClassA object to this cresteClassB method even their attributes and class name is the same just from different package?

Comment: I think you would be able to do that if change your method definition something like this, `public void createClassB (ClassA a) { }`. Now you would be able to pass `ClassA` type of object as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

A little different solution, which is odd, and which you probably aren't looking for, but anyway:

1. Annotate both classes with the same annotations
2. When marshalling, put only your `ClassA` in the JAXB Context
3. When unmarshalling, put only your `ClassB` in the JAXB Context

Comment: Hi what you mean by Annotate both classes with same annotations?

Comment: JAXB has annotations, with which you can configure your classes details. @XmlType, @XmlElement, etc. Use the same annotations (or the same xml, if you like) on both classes. This is more of a workaround, though.